# Issue with users logging onto terminal server

Tags: windows-terminal-services

We have a certain number of users who cannot login on the TS server we have running here. When connecting the server says Please wait for user profile service, loading desktop and then goes straight to logging off and then the connection closes. 
We are running Server2008 R2, 64bit on Hyper-V.

As i said this isnt affecting everyone, so far only two users cannot get in, everyone else can. We have tried deleting their profile so it recreates itself (deleting C>User>%username% and the SID in regedit).
Has anyone else seen this before or had something similar?
If there is any other information needed i can post

Comment: What about GPOs? logon scripts? if the TSs are in NLB cluster, maybe there something on one of the servers? have you tried looking in the event log?